# why cannot use (type func(string)) as type func(interface{}) in assignment

Tags: go

Please first have a look at the code below.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type InterfaceFunc func(interface{})
type StringFunc func(string)

func stringFunc(s string) {
    fmt.Printf("%v", s)
}

func interfaceFunc(i interface{}) {
    fmt.Printf("%v", i)
}

func main() {
    var i = interfaceFunc
    var s = stringFunc

    i = s // I would like someone to explain why this can't be done exactly.
}
```

Run at https://play.golang.org/p/16cE4O3eb95

Why an `InterfaceFunc` can't hold a `StringFunc` while an `interface{}` can hold a `string`.

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you call `i` with something which is not a string?

Comment: @tkausl sorry, what?! I defined it to take `interface{}` so why should I be concerned with what happens if it called with something which is not a string?

Comment: From the FAQ: https://golang.org/doc/faq#covariant_types and https://golang.org/doc/faq#t_and_equal_interface

Comment: Because if your code were allowed, `stringFunc(s string)` would be called with something which may not be a string.

Comment: Thank you guys. The answer is so obvious! guess I just needed to take some sleep last night!

Answer (score 2):

You can not do `s = i` or `i = s`, and the reason is both functions are of different type (different signatures), you can not just assign one type with another in golang.

Also `type InterfaceFunc func(interface{}) type StringFunc func(string)` are sitting there doing nothing.

Comment: I have made a [goplayground](https://play.golang.org/p/ygIOlo7phIS)  for your better understanding.